# Difference between postgeSQL table contrains, sequelize options and sequelize validation?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

Difference between postgeSQL table contrains, sequelize options and sequelize validation?

For example:

What is the difference between:

```
 title: { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false},
```

and

```
 title: { type: Sequelize.STRING, validate: { notNull: true }
```

and

```
 CREATE TABLE mytable( username TEXT NOT NULL )
```

In the [documentation](https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/2.0/docs/models-definition/) they say:

```
 // setting allowNull to false will add NOT NULL to the column, which means an error will be
 // thrown from the DB when the query is executed if the column is null. If you want to check that a value
 // is not null before querying the DB, look at the validations section below.
```

Why would the error be thrown from the db yet the constrain is in a sequelize model definition? Why not just throw it from sequelize? What is the purpose of the model definition then? Another thing that is confusing me is why we need extra validation from the 'validate option' yet we have constrains in the model as well.

Also what will happen if we put a constrain in the postgreSQL table and not in sequelize model or vice versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that `allowNull: false` directly translates to `NOT NULL` constraint when this ORM creates tables.

From https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/models-definition.html

> // setting allowNull to false will add NOT NULL to the column, which means an error will be
>
> // thrown from the DB when the query is executed if the column is null.

That is, first and third snippets are equivalent, provided that tables are created with ORM.

Validation in the second snippet happens on the "client" side (that is, when you run your JS code). If you have validation only, but not a constraint in the database then you can set NULL values e.g. by using some other client. If you have a database constraint then no matter what client do you use, you can't set NULL value.